# Does upgrading to 64-bit Access fix "System Resource Exceeded" error

Tags: ms-access, ms-office

I look after a database that has been plagued by the [System Resource Exceeded](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2726928) error since upgrading from Access 2007 to 2010.

All the hotfixes and reg key changes have been tried, none of which have fully solved the issue, so instead have had to reduce the amount of work performed by any query which throws this error (sometimes have even had to resort to adding `ID mod 2 = 0` to the `WHERE`, then copying the query and changing it to `ID mod 2 = 1` in the copy).

As far as I can gather the root of this problem is running 32-bit Office on 64-bit machines (which we do) so my question is whether anyone has had experience of receiving this error in 32-bit, then upgrading to 64-bit and if this then fully resolved the error?

And as a side question, did you experience any noticeable performance improvements when running 64-bit, as presumably this allows Access to make use of all available memory?

**Update**

Although I wasn't able to get an answer to this question, I have found a fix that so far has always been able to resolve this error, but it's a very strange one. Any index field being referenced in the WHERE clause, if you surround it with `Nz`, but also use the field as the second argument, this resolves it, at least it does for me.

e.g. 
instead of

`WHERE ReportDate = Date`

use

`WHERE Nz(ReportDate,ReportDate) = Date`

Comment: This error can appear in many situations and may not be related to 32-64 bits. For instance, I caught this error when I used wrong answer constant in NotInList event in form, it caused a dead loop of updates.  This errror may not be linked to used system memory. Please provide more details when you receive this error

Comment: Nearly all the instances that I get this error are during update queries, which are generally fairly simple (i.e. there isn't loads of joins etc) but are operating over a large number of records, usually over 1 million. I've also had this occur in various other places, sometimes just building a simple `SELECT` query can throw it. I suspect the size of the database (and the fact have had to use several external linked databases) may be the true 'root' of the problem, but upscaling to SQL Server isn't an option in the short term, so am trying to establish if 64bit Access could help

Comment: In this case upgrade to 64 should solve the problem. Check file size during operations: it may easily reach 2 gigs even if "pure" data size is no more than 300 megs. You will need to change API calls interface, it's quite easy. But moving to SQL is the best solution, think about it, it's not so hard.

Answer (score -2):

This problem may be solved by upgrade to Office 64 bit for large databases due removing 2Gb file size limit. I didn't notice any performance changes on 64 bit Office version.

Comment: Are you saying that the 64-bit version of the Access Database Engine can work with Access database files larger than 2GB? If so, that is apparently **not** true (ref: [here](http://www.slyman.org/blog/2010/11/64-bit-windows-7office-2010-migration-experiences/) and elsewhere).

Comment: Yes, you right, for Access the 2gb limit remains, just tried it. But anyway, the problem may be not in file size because in case of reaching 2Gb Access gives another error, not System Resources Exceeded

Comment: The question I'm really asking is whether using 64-bit Access allows it to make use of more than 2GB of memory, even though the file size is still capped at 2GB (I do find this a little strange given that 64-bit Excel allows file sizes over 2GB, but perhaps MS just realise Access won't scale up well and don't want to encourage large DB files). There is a dedicated error message about using more than 2GB memory in a query, and my guess is "System Resource Exceeded" is related to this error, hence would a 64-bit version resolve it, or is it not optimised to use all available memory in that way?

Comment: Office 32-bit is better compared to Office 64-bit, while working with huge data. Because Office with will send 64-bit set of instructions at a time and overloads the RAM and hence will get "System resource Exceed" error. We actually downgraded from 64-bit to 32-bit office and now working fine with huge data.